# error opening web version react native in VS

Tags: reactjs, react-native, visual-studio-code

I write in terminal **npm start** and after that I choose to run in web version. And i get this error
I tried to fix this problem like that  "**npm install react-native-web**" But it didn't work

- It looks like you're trying to use web support but don't have the required dependencies installed.
- Please install react-native-web@~0.18.7, react-dom@18.0.0,
  @expo/webpack-config@^0.17.0 by running:
- npx expo install react-native-web@~0.18.7 react-dom@18.0.0
  @expo/webpack-config@^0.17.0
- If you're not using web, please ensure you remove the "web" string
  from the platforms array in the project Expo config.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this command: expo start --web

Answer (score 1):

Installing both with legacy peer deps worked for me

```
npm i react-native-web --legacy-peer-deps
npm i react-dom --legacy-peer-deps
```

Answer (score 0):

Install using this command:

1. Open Visual Studio Code terminal in the folder to install
2. `npx expo install react-native-web@~0.18.7`
3. `npm install @expo/webpack-config@^0.17.0`
4. `npm install react-dom@18.0`
5. Run this app with `npm start`

Answer (score 0):

After struggling all the day to find the solution, it finally solved it this way,

`npx expo install expo/webpack-config -- --force.`

Note: I'm working on windows computer

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone get face the issues.
it works for window in my case.I did twice for the practicing  [No more errors I am ready to start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWdim.png)  on the project.

1. first create app from "npx create-expo-app" as the root project not
   from React Native.
2. cd [your app]
3. npx react-native@latest init [yourapp]
4. yarn add @expo/webpack-config

please noted use yarn to install webpack-config not npm install it not gonna work.
done you are ready to go...